# Use wmic process to list only processes that have visible windows

Tags: wmic

I am trying to provide a secondary backup to Windows sometimes working, sometimes not, state restore post update restarts.

Have got the `commandLine` value, which often contains the file open in a visible window (and more should have this, I figure, once this is scripted to open thing scripted post restart). See below

`wmic /output:C:\temp\ProcessList.txt process get Caption, CommandLine`

What I am missing is the ability to tell processes that have windows, compared to not, to filter out all the things that are launched in sub processes by programs, hence have a command line value filled. And other random background processes.

I checked out `tasklist` first, and it would identify things that had a window title, but that wasn't just the displaying visible windows. And, I think, it didn't give `CommandLine` values.

Has anyone got an idea how to get, or extrapolate that?

Comment: See if this helps you.  ...........     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71508736/how-to-filter-out-wmic-process-when-searching-for-a-process-with-a-specific-comm

Comment: @John That answer seems to be about filtering results. I need to find visible windows.

Comment: The above was as close as I could get.